# How to convert vavr collection to Java array?

Tags: vavr

I know about https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/Value.html#toJavaArray but it's deprecated. Is there a non-deprecated method that can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the three `toJavaArray` variants, only the `toJavaArray(Class)` variant is deprecated directly, the other two are marked as deprecated because the `Value` class itself is deprecated. The generated javadoc is not very helpful in distinguishing between the two, unfortunately, but you can check the [source code](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/blob/vavr-1.0.0-alpha-3/src/main/java/io/vavr/Value.java#L617-L718) directly. This picture is probably a more precise representation of the current state: [image: screenshot showing IntelliJ IDEA with the toJavaArray methods in the Value class, with deprecation warnings]

`Value` is deprecated in favor of [`io.vavr.Iterable`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/Iterable.html). This new interface is an extension of the `java.lang.Iterable` type, that differs mainly in that it returns an [`io.vavr.collection.Iterator`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/latest/io/vavr/collection/Iterator.html) instead of a simple `java.util.Iterator`. `io.vavr.collection.Iterator` extends `Value`, and I expect that after the removal of the `Value` interface, all methods which are not explicitly deprecated in the `Value` interface will be moved to `io.vavr.collection.Iterator`.

Out of the two not explicitly deprecated `toJavaArray` methods I would use the `T[] toJavaArray(IntFunction<T[]> arrayFactory)` variant – which was one of my contributions to the vavr project –, as it returns a typed array of the correct type instead of an `Object[]`.

To sum it up, instead of using `vavrValue.toJavaArray()`, I would use `vavrValue.iterator().toJavaArray(SomeType[]::new)`.